# how to direct page to another page in ASP.NET using Autentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, redirect, master-pages

```
LdapAuthentication adAuth = new LdapAuthentication(adPath);
  try
  {
    if(true == adAuth.IsAuthenticated(txtDomain.Text, txtUsername.Text, txtPassword.Text))
    {
      //You can redirect now.
      Server.Transfer("~/WebForm2.aspx");
    }
```

I want to move login page to default (webform.2), but the result is Error executing child request for ~/WebForm2.aspx. Did i write wrong code? or maybe i lost some code.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
Response.Redirect("WebForm2.aspx", false);
```

or if webform is placed in any other folder. then with complete path

```
Response.Redirect("~/pages/WebForm2.aspx", false);
```

Comment: still  Error executing child request for ~/WebForm2.aspx.

Comment: if i'm not add <form> to html body page the website run, but when i adding <form> the website cannot be run.

Comment: could you post the exact error which you are getting?

Comment: Error executing child request for ~/WebForm2.aspx.

Comment: The content of WebForm2 is
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <p></p>
    <form>
      <asp:></asp:>
    </form>
</body>

Comment: Make sure you are writing the correct name of the file webform2.aspx or WebForm2.aspx. It could be due case sense.

Comment: i write correct name, if i'm just add <p>Hello</p> in body page, the website run. but when i write <asp:></asp:>, the website wil be eror

Comment: The issue is with  <asp:></asp:> because it is not complete tag. May I know for what purpose you are using it?

Comment: Generally you are write an asp tag like this <asp:ContentPlaceHolder ID="Content" runat="server">
    </asp:ContentPlaceHolder>